# Apply reveal effect to an InkToolbar [UWP]

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to apply the reveal effect to the buttons of an `InkToolbar` but the code that the documentation reccomends for custom controls doesn't work, here's what I added to the XAML code of the `InkToolbar`:

```
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Target="RootGrid.(RevealBrushHelper.State)" Value="PointerOver" />
                            <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBackgroundPointerOver}"/>
                            <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBorderBrushPointerOver}"/>
                            <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPointerOver}"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Target="RootGrid.(RevealBrushHelper.State)" Value="Pressed" />
                            <Setter Target="RootGrid.Background" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBackgroundPressed}"/>
                            <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBorderBrushPressed}"/>
                            <Setter Target="ContentPresenter.Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPressed}"/>
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simply apply the *Reveal effect* on the entire `InkToolbar`. Instead, you should do it on each of the toolbar buttons.

Because each button uses a different style, this makes applying the effect a lot difficult than I thought. I had to grab a lot of resources from

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.16xxx.0\Generic\generic.xaml

and manually put them in my `App.xaml`. For example, the following style will be applied to the first button on the `InkToolbar` only.

```
<Style x:Key="InkToolbarCommonButtonStyle"
       TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth"
            Value="{ThemeResource InkToolbarButtonWidth}" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight"
            Value="{ThemeResource InkToolbarButtonHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="MaxWidth"
            Value="{ThemeResource InkToolbarButtonWidth}" />
    <Setter Property="MaxHeight"
            Value="{ThemeResource InkToolbarButtonHeight}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="{ThemeResource InkToolbarButtonForegroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin"
            Value="-3" />
</Style>

<Style TargetType="InkToolbarBallpointPenButton"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource InkToolbarCommonButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId"
            Value="InkToolbarBallpointPenButton" />
    <Setter Property="MinStrokeWidth"
            Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="MaxStrokeWidth"
            Value="24" />
    <Setter Property="SelectedStrokeWidth"
            Value="4" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="SelectedBrushIndex"
            Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="InkToolbarBallpointPenButton">
                <Grid x:Name="RootElement"
                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                      Width="{ThemeResource InkToolbarButtonWidth}"
                      Height="{ThemeResource InkToolbarButtonHeight}"
                      BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />

                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="RootElement.(RevealBrush.State)"
                                            Value="PointerOver" />
                                    <Setter Target="RootElement.Background"
                                            Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="RootElement.BorderBrush"
                                            Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBorderBrushPointerOver}" />
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Foreground"
                                            Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="RootElement.(RevealBrush.State)"
                                            Value="Pressed" />
                                    <Setter Target="RootElement.Background"
                                            Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBackgroundPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="RootElement.BorderBrush"
                                            Value="{ThemeResource ButtonRevealBorderBrushPressed}" />
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Foreground"
                                            Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentBackground.Fill"
                                            Value="{ThemeResource InkToolbarDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Foreground"
                                            Value="{ThemeResource InkToolbarDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    <Setter Target="CheckedContent.Foreground"
                                            Value="{ThemeResource InkToolbarDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExtensionGlyph.Foreground"
                                            Value="{ThemeResource InkToolbarDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Indeterminate" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="Content.Opacity"
                                            Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Target="CheckedContent.Opacity"
                                            Value="1" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionAccent.Opacity"
                                            Value="1" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="GlyphVisualStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="ShowExtensionGlyph">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ExtensionGlyph.Opacity"
                                            Value="1" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="HideExtensionGlyph" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FlowDirectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="LeftToRight" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="RightToLeft">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="ContentTransform.ScaleX"
                                            Value="-1" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ButtonFlyoutDirectionStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="BottomDirection" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="TopDirection">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionAccent.VerticalAlignment"
                                            Value="Bottom" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExtensionGlyph.HorizontalAlignment"
                                            Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExtensionGlyph.VerticalAlignment"
                                            Value="Top" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExtensionGlyph.Margin"
                                            Value="0,4,0,0" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExtensionGlyph.Text"
                                            Value="&#xE96D;" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="RightDirection">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionAccent.HorizontalAlignment"
                                            Value="Right" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionAccent.VerticalAlignment"
                                            Value="Stretch" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionAccent.Height"
                                            Value="auto" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionAccent.Width"
                                            Value="2" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExtensionGlyph.HorizontalAlignment"
                                            Value="Right" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExtensionGlyph.VerticalAlignment"
                                            Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExtensionGlyph.Margin"
                                            Value="0,0,4,0" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExtensionGlyph.Text"
                                            Value="&#xE26B;" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="LeftDirection">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionAccent.HorizontalAlignment"
                                            Value="Left" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionAccent.VerticalAlignment"
                                            Value="Stretch" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionAccent.Height"
                                            Value="auto" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionAccent.Width"
                                            Value="2" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExtensionGlyph.HorizontalAlignment"
                                            Value="Left" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExtensionGlyph.VerticalAlignment"
                                            Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExtensionGlyph.Margin"
                                            Value="4,0,0,0" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExtensionGlyph.Text"
                                            Value="&#xE26C;" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="RightDirectionRTL">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionAccent.HorizontalAlignment"
                                            Value="Right" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionAccent.VerticalAlignment"
                                            Value="Stretch" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionAccent.Height"
                                            Value="auto" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionAccent.Width"
                                            Value="2" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExtensionGlyph.HorizontalAlignment"
                                            Value="Right" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExtensionGlyph.VerticalAlignment"
                                            Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExtensionGlyph.Margin"
                                            Value="0,0,4,0" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExtensionGlyph.Text"
                                            Value="&#xE26C;" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="LeftDirectionRTL">
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionAccent.HorizontalAlignment"
                                            Value="Left" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionAccent.VerticalAlignment"
                                            Value="Stretch" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionAccent.Height"
                                            Value="auto" />
                                    <Setter Target="SelectionAccent.Width"
                                            Value="2" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExtensionGlyph.HorizontalAlignment"
                                            Value="Left" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExtensionGlyph.VerticalAlignment"
                                            Value="Center" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExtensionGlyph.Margin"
                                            Value="4,0,0,0" />
                                    <Setter Target="ExtensionGlyph.Text"
                                            Value="&#xE26B;" />
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

                    <Rectangle x:Name="ContentBackground"
                               Fill="Transparent" />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="ExtensionGlyph"
                               Style="{StaticResource InkToolbarExtensionGlyphStyle}"
                               AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
                    <Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5">
                        <Grid.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform x:Name="ContentTransform" />
                        </Grid.RenderTransform>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="Content"
                                   Style="{StaticResource InkToolbarGlyphFontStyle}"
                                   Text="&#xE76D;"
                                   AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                   Canvas.ZIndex="1"
                                   Foreground="{ThemeResource InkToolbarButtonForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="CheckedContent"
                                   Style="{StaticResource InkToolbarGlyphFontStyle}"
                                   Text="&#xE76D;"
                                   AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                   Canvas.ZIndex="1"
                                   Foreground="{ThemeResource InkToolbarButtonSelectedForegroundThemeBrush}"
                                   Opacity="0" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="ContentFillGlyph"
                                   Text="&#xE88F;"
                                   Style="{StaticResource InkToolbarGlyphFillFontStyle}"
                                   TextAlignment="Center"
                                   AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"
                                   Opacity="1"
                                   Canvas.ZIndex="0"
                                   Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=SelectedBrush, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </Grid>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionAccent"
                               Style="{StaticResource InkToolbarSelectionAccentStyle}" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Please note that I had to replace `RevealBrushHelper` with `RevealBrush`. The [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/reveal) is using the former though. It could be that I am using an older version of Windows 10 SDK (*16232*) or the doc is not up-to-date. So pick whatever that doesn't break. :)

Also, in order for the light to show, you will have to put your `InkToolbar` on a darker background.

```
<Border Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" Grid.Row="1">
    <InkToolbar Margin="24" />
</Border>
```

I have created a sample [here](https://github.com/JustinXinLiu/InkToolbarRevealStyleRepo) with all the *reveal lighting enabled* button styles and below is a working demo. Enjoy! :)

[image]